# How to display images in a row html

Tags: html

I'm trying to display images from my PC on my website, i've tried using floats but nothing works. Everything I try ends up the same:

```
<div class="feat">
    <img src="nirvana.jpeg" style="width:50%;height:50%;" align="left";>
    <img src="pup.jpg" style="width:50%;height:50%;" align="right";>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your image files located?

Comment: You can't access a local file (on your computer) from the website (on the online server). Put the image in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the align left and right and white space between image tags.

```
<div class="feat">
   <img src="nirvana.jpeg" style="width:50%;height:50%;"><img src="pup.jpg" style="width:50%;height:50%;">
</div>
```

Read up [this blog post](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) about white space. Here is a working plunkr (without your images, obviously): http://embed.plnkr.co/sytM7HeFUVDPT1p3HoXN/preview

Comment: I don't think the align is the problem. Tried the same code just replaced the image file and it still works.

Comment: How did you solve your problem @hinton? Better post it here so other will know too

Comment: I copied what Dara posted

Comment: sorry @dara I misunderstood hinton question